# Pop-up box not opening when using PHP Database Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using this PHP Database Ajax code by [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

This is my code, inside the PHP File (as shown in w3schools). It is working in this snippet. Also working, when i use this in the HTML file (as shown in w3schools).

But when, i use this code in the PHP File, it is not working. What could possibly go wrong?

```css
.playtrailer {
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 color:red;
 font-weight:600;
 border:none;
 padding:10px 12px;
}

.playtrailer:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#e2e2e2;
}

#trailerdivbox {
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0%;overflow:auto;
 background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


.videoWrapper {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:25px;
 margin:auto;
 height:0;top:100px;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position:absolute;
 max-width:560px;
 max-height:315px;
 width:95%;
 height:95%;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
 <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="naQr0uTrH_s"> Play Trailer &#9658; </button> 
 
  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="naaQr0uTrH_s"> Play Trailer &#9658; </button> 

<!-- Watch Video Pop-up box -->
<div id='close'>
  <div id='trailerdivbox'>
    <div class='videoWrapper'>
      <iframe id='video' class='trailervideo' width='560' height='315' data-src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/' src='about:blank' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Script to open Pop-up box when someone click on watch video button -->
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.playtrailer')

function playVideo(src) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+src + '?autoplay=1'; //add with iframe
}

function resetVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

  video.src = '';
  video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.forEach(function(a){
a.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  playVideo(this.dataset.src); // pass the src
}
})

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetVideo();
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit: This is my HTML file (Copy/pasted from w3schools)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP file (getuser.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.playtrailer {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    color:red;
    font-weight:600;
    border:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
}

.playtrailer:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
}

#trailerdivbox {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;overflow:auto;
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


.videoWrapper {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:25px;
    margin:auto;
    height:0;top:100px;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:560px;
    max-height:315px;
    width:95%;
    height:95%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

 <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="naQr0uTrH_s"> Play Trailer &#9658; </button> 

  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="naaQr0uTrH_s"> Play Trailer &#9658; </button> 

<!-- Watch Video Pop-up box -->
<div id='close'>
  <div id='trailerdivbox'>
    <div class='videoWrapper'>
      <iframe id='video' class='trailervideo' width='560' height='315' data-src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/' src='about:blank' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Script to open Pop-up box when someone click on watch video button -->
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('trailerdivbox');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.playtrailer')

function playVideo(src) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+src + '?autoplay=1'; //add with iframe
}

function resetVideo() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var src = video.src.replace('?autoplay=1', '');

  video.src = '';
  video.src = src;
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.forEach(function(a){
a.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  playVideo(this.dataset.src); // pass the src
}
})

var trailerbox = document.getElementById("close");

trailerbox.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetVideo();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetVideo();
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it's working, here, but not working in the PHP? If you've provided us a working example, how can we help you? We don't know what the PHP-integrated version looks like. You will have to play "spot the difference" between this and the PHP. Check your console for errors, check the server for errors.

Comment: @ADyson sir check the W3Schools code. I just put my code inside that PHP file provided by W3schools, that's all

Comment: ok, thanks. So, we need some info from your debugging attempts. Where does it fail? Which bits work, and which bits don't? What errors and/or unexpected behaviour do you get when you try to use it?

Comment: @ADyson sir, In the PHP File (getuser.php), the button gets displayed. But no pop-up window appears. 

This code is so simple, their must be either a small mistake or it is not possible in PHP ajax. 

My code is working. PHP Ajax Database is also working. But the pop-up box code inside PHP ajax file is not working.

Comment: So, what's the flow? Are you trying to run the "HTML" page, and call getuser.php via ajax? Or are you displaying "getuser.php" in a separate browser tab? It's not clear what you're doing. If it's the first scenario, it will never work because you can't embed an entire HTML page (with `<html>` tags and all) inside another HTML element, it makes the page invalid. That W3Schools example is junk (as is a lot of their content, I would find another tutorial). It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - the example is about listing users, but then you're trying to embed videos in it.

Comment: Is the user part of it even related to what you're doing? Especially since you removed the PHP which would generate the list. The whole thing looks like a bit of a mess.

Comment: @ADyson sir, You got it. It is the 1st part. I am trying to run "HTML" page and call getuser.php via ajax. 

 I just tried to remove the <body><html> tag, but still no pop-up.. So it is not possible? Or i need different code, completely??

Comment: remove this: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>` and this `</head>
<body>` and this `</body>
</html>` from getUser.php. That should just render the necessary bits into the AJAX response. Then see if it works. Again, report any errors that occur.

Comment: I tried to do that, but same problem. No error, nothing like that. Buttons appear, but pop-up box don't. @ADyson sir, you can use this code in your xampp/wampp, you just need to copy/paste it. If you are free enough, thanks a lot :)